# What javascript techniques are used in this array parser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have the following script that dumps a given array's contents

```
   function dump(obj) {
            obj = obj || {};
            var result = [];
            $.each(obj, function (key, value) { result.push('"' + key + '":"' + value + '"'); });
            return '{' + result.join(',') + '}';
        }
```

... but I don't understand the "array" functions of this. Can you tell me what I need to learn to comprehend what is going within the .each statement?

**Update**

`e.values` below is an example of what obj looks like.

[image]

Comment: Just FYI, this code is pretty much just re-creating `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: The problem with your function is that Number and Boolean values will be wrapped in quotes which effectively changes their type to String. I recommend the built-in `JSON.stringify()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is using jQuery for the `each` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/ to do the iterating. Here is what happens in your `dump` `function`:

```
function dump(obj) {
    // If 'obj' is falsy then make 'obj' a new Object
    obj = obj || {};

    // Create a new Array
    var result = [];

    // Loop over each property in 'obj' and add
    // "key":"val" String to the 'result' Array,
    $.each(obj, function (key, value) { result.push('"' + key + '":"' + value + '"'); });

    // Join the Array using "," as the delimiter and wrap
    // this with { ... }. Example of arr.join():
    //     var arr = [1, 2, 3];
    //     console.log(arr.join(".")); // "1.2.3"
    //     console.log(arr.join("|")); // "1|2|3"
    return '{' + result.join(',') + '}';
}
```

**Edit**
If you need to get the key(s) of an arbitrary `Object` you can use:

```
function getKeys(obj) {
    var keys = [],
        i;
    for (var i in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            keys.push(i);
        }
    }
    return keys;
}

var keys = getKeys({key: "value"}); // ["key"]
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/LFXxh/).

You could also have a look at Underscore.js's  [_.keys()](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#keys).

Comment: Thanks a ton!  I'll be studying that closely.  Can you tell me alternative ways to access the "key" of the obj?  Assuming that obj is always has a length of one?

Comment: Glad it helped :-) An `Object` will potentially have many keys; not just one. For example: `var o = {a: "b", c: "d"}`. This `Object` has two keys: `a` and `c`. You can access the values of these keys in a couple of ways: `var val = o.a;` or `var key = "a"; var val = o[key]`.

Comment: When I attempt `o[key]` I get an undefined for key.  I updated the question with an example.  How do I extract the string `EntryCommentPublic1DropDown`

Comment: If you give the `key` variable a value of `"EntryCommentPublic1DropDown"` it should work or you could just do it literally, i.e. `e.values.EntryCommentPublic1DropDown`.

Comment: The issue I have is that I don't know the value of the key beforehand.  I simply need to get the name of the key.  The bigger picture here is that I'm handling the `Save()` event of a grid in cell edit mode.  I have no idea which column is being edited, and the column name is within the key.... I need to handle some columns differently than the others.

Answer (score 1):

Basically all that code is doing is creating a string version of the object.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GYJAT/

---

The `$.each` is a jQuery function that goes through the array.

Comment: Would this be an "associative array"?  I'm trying to understand how I can access the keys of an array.

Comment: @makerofthings7 Javascript doesn't really have associated arrays. It is an object (not an array), which could more appropriately be thought of as a key value store. Arrays are inherently ordered, objects are inherently unordered.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments you left, it seems that your main question is about how to get the keys of an object.

First, in your code sample jQuery does it automatically for you as part of the each function:

$.each(obj, function (key, value) ...

If you need to do it yourself, modern browsers have the keys property: Object.keys(obj)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

With older browsers, you'll need to use a for loop (note the HasOwnProperty test):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/HasOwnProperty#Example:_Iterating_over_the_properties_of_an_object